# Action on reply button in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am really new in java and especially developing mobile apps using Android studio.

Please can someone help me with the action code for a reply button on a chat message. For example in WhatsApp, you can reply a text while the sent text is attached to your reply. That's what I want. I will be very grateful if someone kindly helps me.

Comment: can you add an image? I did not understand what you mean

Comment: Let me display these pictures from WhatsApp so you see what I mean

Comment: I need 10 reputation before I can be able to post an image.

Comment: Let me try to explain in another way. When you open WhatsApp and see a message from a particular user, you swipe the message from the user to the right and it wraps or links the message from the user to the Edittext field. Whatever you write in the Edittext field and send becomes a direct reply to the message from that user. I am not asking for the java code responsible for replying chats as such.

Comment: Ok.You mean replying a message.I did not try it before this question answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures and you can write inside of swipe left or right (whatever you want) TextView.getText.toString and set this text wherever you want i hope it works.

Comment: How can I set the TextView.getText.toString to the Edittext box so that when I reply the textview, the reply with be attached to the Textview???